# jQuery $(this).find

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a simple animation on a div named ‘slide’ when a link is clicked; then head to the new document (href from a).
So far, I came up with this

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.slide').animate({
        right: '-100%' //animation on absolute positioned div
    },1000, function() {
        location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});
```

and nothing happens.
If I get rid of ‘this’ – like so…

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.slide').animate({
        right: '-100%' //animation on absolute positioned div
    },1000, function() {
        location.href = $(‘a’).attr("href");
    });
});
```

… animation works fine, but instead of following selected link, it follows the first link on the page (understandably).

Anyone has an idea what’s wrong with the 1st example?

Comment: $(this).find('.slide').animate() and $('.slide').animate() may vary  a lot of difference in different contexts. the first requires the slide to be the descendant of the current element. the second does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `event.target` :

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.slide').animate({
      right: '-100%' //animation on absolute positioned div
   },1000, function() {
      location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
   });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `$(this)`  in a different `variable`

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);   //             <------------------- like this
  $(this).find('.slide').animate({
    right: '-100%'//animation on absolute positioned div
  },1000, function() {
    location.href = $this.attr("href");  // <---------  use $this here
  });
});
```

Comment: why dont you call it `$a` or something other than `$this` so as not to confuse with `$(this)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , This line in Question makes it clear `--->`  `location.href = $(‘a’).attr("href");`

Comment: @MohammadAdil ohh right. But than rather this line `$(this).find('.slide').animate({` :)

Comment: And why use $? You can easily do:

var that = $(this);

Don't forget the var, otherwise, you are declaring it globally.

Comment: @dekomote `$` is just to make it clear that it's a jquery variable.. and yeah `var` should be there.

Answer (score 0):

try document ready and live

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('a').on('click','',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.slide').animate({
        right: '-100%' //animation on absolute positioned div
    },1000, function() {
        location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});
});
```

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated from version 1.7 and removed from version 1.9 onwards.